# Last Digit Of N^M

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Given $N,M$ What is the best way to find last digit of $N^M$ if both $N,M$ Can be as large as $10^{18}$?

EXAMPLE : if $N=2$ and $M=4$ then answer would be $6$.

Comment: Hint: Calculate [mod 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: @vadim123 I need to calculate it without evaluating the power as N and M are quite large

Comment: @user3001932 Use modular exponentiation, and things will go a bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the value $N ( mod 10 ) $ and then raise this value to power M. Now as $ 0 < N ( mod 10 ) < 9 $ thus power of that to any large M , we can easily determine the unit's place.